# SSRS Page Widths

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report with an interactive size of 8.5/11, margins set at 0.25, the page size is set to 8.5/11, the body is 8.0w and the report is 8.0w, but for some reason when I export to excel it doesn't fit on a single page. Any ideas what could be causing this? I have other reports with the same setup that do fit to a page. Same printer setup as the other reports too.

Answer (score 0):

Excel accounts for a very tiny amount of space for the grid separation. So when you export to excel the report is widened and lengthened slightly. Usually its not an issue but if you have a large number of columns in said report the number of separations is going to be greater pushing you over that tipping point. You can do 1 of 2 things. 1. Change the width of your report to account for this space added by excel or 2. export to PDF for printing purposes as it is not going to alter the width of your report and allow for your expected printing outcome.